# Using Mean.io for my SPA application

Tags: node.js, angularjs, mean.io

I have a new project which will consist of two parts...a client - SPA using AngularJS and server side using Nodejs - MongoDB. Many articles recommend using Mean.io when developing similar projects, but couldn't find any information on why this is better than simply installing Nodejs, Mongo, AngularJS and using them.

So can someone please tell me the benefits of using Mean.io over installing Node, Mongo, Angular and Express and using them? OR in other words why it is better to use Mean.io rather than downloading and installing each package/ framework individually? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

well, you are going to save a lot of time with plain simple boilerplate code, in my case I've been using [meanjs](http://meanjs.org/) which helps you with a lot of basic functions like:

- **login** using passport, local strategies, social network strategies (g+, facebook, twitter)
- Twitter bootstrap
- Consistent folder structure
- Consistent file naming
- Environment configuration for dependencies and custom "settings" (dev, test, production)
- pre configured routes with controllers

**software development workflow:**

- grunt (preconfigures task like jshint, build, test)
- yeoman generator (save you a lot of time)
- nodemon (for reloading pages everytime you save a page)
- testing frameworks for client and server side

I can list a lot of more but the point is to mention the benefits are far beyond just by putting all 4 main pieces of software together.

for more info you can look at the [overview](http://meanjs.org/docs.html#overview)